# Java sort by selection: which is better in regards to readability and efficiency?

Tags: java, sorting, comparative-review

Which algorithm do you think is better in regards to readability and efficiency?

**`selection()`:**

```
public static int[] selection(int[] tab) {
    int minor;
    int aux;
    for (int i=0; i<tab.length-1; i++) {
        minor = tab[i];
        for (int j=i+1; j<=tab.length-1; j++) {
            if (tab[j] < minor) {
                aux = tab[j];
                tab[j] = minor;
                minor = aux;
            }
        }
        tab[i] = minor;
    }
    return tab;
}
```

**`otherSelection()`:**

```
public static int[] otherSelection(int A[]) {
    int i, j, minor, pos, tmp;
    for (i = 0; i < A.length - 1; i++) {
        minor = A[i]; 
        pos = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < A.length; j++){
            if (A[j] < minor) {
                minor = A[j]; 
                pos = j;
            }
        }
        if (pos != i){
            tmp = A[i];
            A[i] = A[pos];
            A[pos] = tmp;
        }
    }
    return A;
}
```

Comment: I think you'll have better luck with this question [Programmers Exchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Better in what sense?  Readability?  Efficiency? Maintainability?  etc

Comment: Mainly in readibility and efficency. Which one do you like the most? Thank you.

Comment: May I introduce a feature that's around since Java 1.5 (or nearly a decade): [enhanced for each loops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2). And please learn about [Collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) (introduced in Java 1.2). And please read [Clean Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0-13-235088-2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Readability:**

The first one is far more readable because it can be translated at so:

```
selection(tab) 
    for each value of tab: i = (0->size-1) 
        minor = tab[i]
        for each value of tab: j = (i->size-1) 
            if (tab[j] < minor) 
                swap(minor, tab[j])
        tab[i] = minor;
    return tab;
```

This is very simple and symmetric.  The `otherSelection` is a bit more difficult to read because it tracks a `pos`.  This is a uncommon way to do this sort (not necessarily bad).  Then it does the swap post inner loop.  This was personally more difficult for me to read.  The first wins here.

**Time Efficiency:**

Both run \$O(n^2)\$.  However, `otherSelection` does only swap once per n-iteration.  This actually is more efficient to do.

**Space Efficiency:**

`selection` only needs 4 int variables where as `otherSelection` needs 5.  It's a bit more space efficient to use `selection`.  As user @200_success mentioned, the space efficiency is the same at worse case since both are constant space \$O(1)\$.  This isn't counting the input space (which you shouldn't really anyways).

**Final verdict:**

`selection` is a better option than `otherSelection` as far as readability.  However, `otherSelection` is better for efficiency.  [This is a better variant](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/arrays/31arrayselectionsort.html) of `otherSelection` which is just as good when it comes to space efficiency:

```
public static void selectionSort2(int[] x) {
    for (int i=0; i<x.length-1; i++) {
        int minIndex = i;      // Index of smallest remaining value.
        for (int j=i+1; j<x.length; j++) {
            if (x[minIndex] > x[j]) {
                minIndex = j;  // Remember index of new minimum
            }
        }
        if (minIndex != i) { 
            //...  Exchange current element with smallest remaining.
            int temp = x[i];
            x[i] = x[minIndex];
            x[minIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

If you care for efficiency, this is the better selection sort option.  You could also do a bit-swap for when swapping the variables.

**Final notes:**  Since this is Java, you don't need to do the `return` statement at the end.

Comment: For all practical purposes, space efficiency is a tie.

Comment: @200_success Yes. In both cases, the worse case space efficiency is constant space.  I was just nitpicking at that point.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of readability, I would go for the first one `selection`. You would like to do everything cleanly inside 2 nested for clarity. Both are \$ O \left( n^{2} \right) \$.

Answer (score 2):

First one is definitely better. More variables you have, the harder it is to follow them. That said, I'd suggest applying some rules:

1. A `<=` comparison is *very* unusual and triggers an unnecessary attention
2. Declare a variable in the scope it it used in
3. Recognize important algorithms and factor them out
4. A loop usually represent an important algorithm

Let's apply the first rule:

```
public static int[] selection(int[] tab) {
    int minor;
    int aux;
    for (int i=0; i<tab.length-1; i++) {
        minor = tab[i];
        for (int j=i+1; j<tab.length; j++) {
            if (tab[j] < minor) {
                aux = tab[j];
                tab[j] = minor;
                minor = aux;
            }
        }
        tab[i] = minor;
    }
    return tab;
}
```

Then the second:

```
public static int[] selection(int[] tab) {
    for (int i=0; i<tab.length-1; i++) {
        int minor = tab[i];
        for (int j=i+1; j<tab.length; j++) {
            if (tab[j] < minor) {
                int aux = tab[j];
                tab[j] = minor;
                minor = aux;
            }
        }
        tab[i] = minor;
    }
    return tab;
}
```

The code in `if` clause is one of the most fundamental algorithms, namely `swap`. I am afraid Java doesn't support swapping the way C++ programmers use; we just can't pass an integer to a function to have it modified. In this particular case Java "deficiency" pushes us to the right direction: what we actually want is to swap values in array - no need for `minor` at all! Here is an application of a third rule (with `swap` provided separately):

```
public static int[] selection(int[] tab) {
    for (int i=0; i<tab.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j=i+1; j<tab.length; j++) {
            if (tab[j] < tab[i]) {
                swap(tab, i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    return tab;
}
```

Now we may focus on the fourth rule: what does the inner loop represent? A `swap` which finally settle the value of `tab[i]` is the smallest `tab[j]` in the range. This would be my final code (`index_of_min` provided separately):

```
public static int[] selection(int[] tab) {
    for (int i=0; i<tab.length-1; i++) {
        int index_of_min = index_of_minimum(tab, i + 1, tab.length);
        if (tab[index_of_min] < tab[i]) {
            swap(tab, i, index_of_min)
        }
    }
    return tab;
}
```

BTW, now an opportunistic optimization is obvious (I am not sure I'd go for it but anyway):

```
public static int[] selection(int[] tab) {
    for (int i=0; i<tab.length-1; i++) {
        int index_of_min = index_of_minimum(tab, i + 1, tab.length);
        if (tab[index_of_min] >= tab[i]) {
            ++i;
        }
        swap(tab, i, index_of_min);
    }
    return tab;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Readability

None of them. Your method and variable names do not express the intent of your code. If you want readability, your code should ["read like well-written prose"](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ReadsLikeProse).